# Using a typeof 'T' when using generics

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I am trying to get my decorator that is attached to a property to show a list of items on a `typeof MyObject` when called like `@MyProperty(MyObject, { /* public properties that are in MyObject */ })`

I have tried using `export function MyProperty<T extends Behavior>(component: typeof T, options?: Options<T>) {` but it gives me an error:

> 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

I have also tried using `InstanceType<T>` like this: `export function MyProperty<T extends Behavior>(component: InstanceType<T>, options?: Options<T>) {` but it gives me this error:

> Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'new (...args: any) => any'.

I have also tried using `typeof Behavior` instead of `typeof T`, however that gives items in the `Behavior` and not the class extending `Behavior`.

I am not quite sure how to do this. How can I get these properties in the second parameter of `@MyProperty`?

```
export type Options<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: T[P]
}

export function MyProperty<T extends Behavior>(component: typeof T, options?: Options<T>) {
  return (target: MyTarget, property: string): void => {

  }
}

export class Item extends MyTarget {
  @MyProperty(Mesh, {color: 'red'})
  public mesh!: Mesh
}

export class Mesh extends Behavior {
  public mesh!: ThreeMesh
  public geometry!: Geometry
  public color: string | number | Color = 0xffffff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`T` already is a type. Therefore `typeof T` is invalid, because `typeof` requires a value (of which it will return the type)

So the correct syntax is:

```
function MyProperty<T extends Behavior>(component: T, options?: Options<T>) { … }
```

Comment: That gives an error: `Argument of type 'typeof Mesh' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Behavior'.`

Comment: Well that is a new error then based on how you used the function. What do you want from the `component` parameter, anyways? If you want to make an instance of it, you can use `new () => T`, if you want to already get an instance of it, you can simply use `T`.

Comment: oh and you might wanna write `class Mesh implements Behavior` instead of `extends`

Comment: What I want to do is find an instance of `Mesh`, `MyComponent`, `MyObject`, etc. and modify it's properties based on what was passed in

Comment: Look like `component: typeof Behavior` and `@MyProperty<Mesh>(Mesh, { color: 'red' })` works if I pass a generic.